# How to run and start mongodb from within nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Basically I don't want to use an existing mongodb database site like the official mongocloud or whatever-- how can I do what they do, but myself? Do I just include the database folder, along with all of the mongodb executable, in my nodejs folder and call require("child_process").spawn("mongodb.exe", /*insert params here*/), or is there some kind of way to do this in the mongo module?

And also do I need my own virtual machine to be able to do this or can the following work on a standard heroku nodejs application for example?
Anyone?

Comment: Why are you launching it from within a Node app? Normally you'd have this service running on a server, even the same server you're running the Node app on.

Comment: @tadman but how would I begin to run it on a server, if not with child_process?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku's hosting solution has only ephemeral volumes, so you can't use it for a database. Any files you create are temporary and will be purged on a regular basis.

For example, when your application is idle Heroku will de-provision that resource and clear out any data you've left there.

You can't use Heroku like this, you must use an external database service, or one of their many add-on offerings.

Comment: But how do I host the mongo database entirely on my own? How do the external database services work?

Comment: Look in the [Heroku Add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons) page for options. There's a number of solutions there for MongoDB. If you want to it entirely on your own then you need to spin up an instance of MongoDB somewhere that has good connectivity to Heroku, so you'll need to do some tests to see what datacenter/provider works best. It could be AWS, Azure, Google Cloud, Linode, Digital Ocean, or some other similar solution. As a note, this is probably *way* more expensive than paying a nominal fee for a managed database.

Comment: But how do I do it without any other service, just ok my own entirely?

Comment: If you've never administered a server before, you're probably not prepared for the responsibility of running a MongoDB server. If you don't set this up properly people there's a very high probability of your server being compromised, and if this is storing important data, of that data being stolen. This happens *all the time* when organizations that should know better cheap out and roll their own solutions, or fail to do even a cursory security check. **Running your own server is extremely risky if you have no experience with MongoDB and server management**.

Comment: Is this for a mission critical application or just experimenting?

Comment: If you're just tinkering, run this all locally. If you're deploying it as a mission critical application I must stress **use a managed service** or you will end up in a world of hurt. Databases are easy to deploy, but even easier to foul up. Heroku has a large marketplace where you can find something that suits your needs.

Comment: I must second @tadman's suggestion here. Please don't treat this lightly, as this is a critical issue, no matter what application you have in mind. Using a managed service is a much better and safer solution.

Comment: @kevinadi ok but this question is not about safety and advice, if I wanted extra advice I would have asked for it, I'm asking how can I actually do this

Comment: @bluejayke "Just tell me where to cut, I can remove the brain tumor myself!" It's reckless and irresponsible to give out advice on how to do this to people that aren't properly prepared to do it.

Comment: @tadman first of all that's not the point of this site: this website is all about questions and *answers*, not about questions and "I don't think I should answer that, because...", Second you don't know how experience I am, I could have have worked for Google and secretly for Microsoft and Intel at the same time, I can be anyone, it's not the job of a standard user to make their own guesses and assessments for if the OP deserves an answer or not, the only job they have is to provide an answer, if they have it, but

Comment: @bluejayke I've been on this site long enough to observe the impact of giving someone advice that's dangerous. We need to prepare people for the consequences of their actions so they can make informed decisions. To omit this step is reckless and unethical. Also working for Google/Intel and/or Microsoft does not make you automatically an expert in anything.